# collectionView highlight cell and hide other cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i need explanation how to highlight selected cell and in the same time disable click on other cells and put them as hide

```
func bringItemToFront (gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    let location : CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.collectionView)
    let swipedIndexPath:NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(location)!
    let swipedcell:UICollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(swipedIndexPath)!

    self.mainView.bringSubviewToFront(self.backImage)
    self.backImage.alpha = 0.9
    self.mainView.bringSubviewToFront(swipedcell)

}
```

in my code i try to push to front the background image and after that push to front the cell 
thanks for the helpers